# For the past 5 days or so something has been accessing my HDD

Tags: windows-7

Something has been accessing my 256GB SSD on my Windows 7 -64 bit computer in the past 5 days like crazy and and i did a wipe and reload 1 and a half months ago so not a lot of software has been on it and I don't know what it is is there anyway to see what it is Ty.

Comment: I read that something is happening to you, but I miss a question and what you have tried to solve it yourself and where you got stuck.

Comment: Can you define the symptoms? Is your system acting sluggish? Is your HDD access light on constantly? Do you see CPU spikes in the task manager? The more info, the better.

Answer (score 0):

So I used Revo uninstaller to clear off some software that I haven't used in a while, my ccleaner needed to be updated so I updated it and ran it; there were roughly 7.3 Gigabytes in just the internet cache that I needed to remove.

I ran the registry part of it and so I guess my computer needed a little bit of a tuneup and yes I noticed before it was acting very sluggish and my HDD indicator light was through the roof and good thing I have a sata 3 SSD because if I had a 7200 - 5400 rpm HDD like my old computer with 7 passes it would take me a long long time to clear it off and thanks so much everyone for your help and sorry for my spelling and grammar.